# innerHTML class

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I am working with a javascript function which takes a value from a `<input type="text" />` and then write it as a text without being an input. I do this using `innerHTML` and it works perfectly.

My question is: How can I use a CSS class to edit the color and size of the text I am writting with `innerHTML`

```
var element = document.getElementById("element");
var value = document.getElementById("value").value;
element.innerHTML = value;
```

Thank You!

Comment: Id suggest using `element.textContent = value;` instead. Modifying the `innerHTML` is icky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript:

```
element.className = 'foo';
// or
element.className += ' foo';
```

CSS:

```
.foo {
    color: #F00;
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

---

> Or, more advanced: `elem.classList.add( 'foo' );` (As usual, IE gets the [polyfill](https://github.com/eligrey/classList.js) via conditional comments.)
>   – Šime Vidas

Comment: Or, more advanced: `elem.classList.add( 'foo' );` (As usual, IE gets the [polyfill](https://github.com/eligrey/classList.js) via conditional comments.)

Answer (score 1):

If your element's ID is "element" just add the following css:

```css
#element{
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

And mess with the values until it suits you.

Answer (score 1):

With JS you can manipulate the css directly without the need of an extra class (besides, you already have an ID, you could use styles on...):
Once you have selected your element

```
var el = document.getElementById("element");
```

you can call

```
el.style.<css-style> = ...;
```

with css-style being a css-declaration. Note that they are not hyphenated but notated with CamelCase -> `backgroundColor` instead of `background-color`.

Firebug can give you content assist on that